# Using $\tan 5\theta = \dfrac{5\tan\theta - 10\tan^3\theta + \tan^5\theta }{1 - 10\tan^2\theta + 5\tan^4\theta}$ solve $x^4 -10x^2 + 5 = 0$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I require some direction with the following.  The question is:

Given

$$ \tan 5\theta = \dfrac{5\tan\theta - 10\tan^3\theta +  \tan^5\theta }{1 - 10\tan^2\theta + 5\tan^4\theta}
$$

Show that the equation

$$ 
x^4 -10x^2 + 5 = 0
$$

has roots $ x = \pm \tan \dfrac{\pi}{5} ,  \pm \tan \dfrac{2\pi}{5} $.

I started this way.  Let $ x = \tan \theta $.

$$ \tan 5\theta = \dfrac{5x - 10x^3 +  x^5 }{1 - 10x^2 + 5x^4}
$$

Let $ \theta = 0 $.

$$ 0 = \dfrac{5x - 10x^3 +  x^5 }{1 - 10x^2 + 5x^4}
$$

$$ 
5x - 10x^3 +  x^5 = 0
$$

$$ x(x^4 - 10x^2 + 5) = 0
$$

$ \therefore x = 0 $ or $ x^4 - 10x^2 + 5 = 0$.

Since

$$  \dfrac{5x - 10x^3 +  x^5 }{1 - 10x^2 + 5x^4} = 0
$$

It follows $ \tan 5\theta = 0 $.

$$ \tan 5\theta = 0 $$
$$ 5\theta = 0, \pi , 2\pi $$
$$ \theta = 0, \frac{\pi}{5} , \frac{2\pi}{5} $$

This is where I require some direction to determine the solutions of the quartic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are more than three solutions to $\tan 5\theta = 0$.

Comment: I realise that, but I can't see how to get the 4 solutions given in the original problem.

Comment: You already have done that, given $\theta$ as $0$, $\pm \pi/5$, $\pm 2\pi/5$, notice that $0$ is not a solution, a quadric function has four solutions, and you have four $\theta$'s which would give you four solutions.

Comment: Note that you want $ \tan 5 \theta = 0 $ and $ \tan \theta \neq 0 $. This is why you exlucde the $ \theta = 0 $ solution.

Comment: "$\displaystyle 5\theta = 0, \pi , 2\pi.~$" : you overlooked $~\color{red}{-\pi, ~-2\pi}.$

Comment: Note that $\tan \pi = \tan 2\pi = \tan 5(\pi /5) = \tan(5 (2 \pi/5)) = 0$, since $\tan \theta \in (-\infty, \infty)$, the solutions are trivial.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$x^4 - 10 x^2 + 5 = 0$

We can apply the quadratic formula to this...

$x^2  = 5\pm \sqrt {20}\\
x = \pm \sqrt {5\pm \sqrt {20}}$

Depending on how we allocate the plusses and minuses that gives us $4$ values of $x,$ each one applying to one of $\{\pm \tan \frac {\pi}{5},\pm \tan \frac {2\pi}{5}\}$

I think I have misinterpreted the question.

You have:

$x(x^4 -10x^2 + 5) = 0$ when $x = \tan \theta$ and $\tan 5\theta = 0$

We exclude the solution $x = 0$ in our evaluation of the quartic and consider the rest.

$\tan 5\theta = 0\\
5\theta = n\pi\\
\theta = \frac {\pi}{5},\frac {2\pi}{5}, \frac {3\pi}{5}, \frac {4\pi}{5}$

For other values of $n,$ we either have $\tan \frac {n\pi}{5} = 0$ or $\tan \frac {n\pi}{5}$ equals the tangent of one of the values above.

Then we can say:
$\tan (\pi - x) = -\tan x$ which tells us that $\tan \frac {3\pi}{5} = -\tan \frac {2\pi}{5}$ and $\tan \frac {4\pi}{5} = -\tan \frac {\pi}{5}$

My work at the begining allows you to express $\tan \frac {n\pi}{5}$ in terms of radicals.

Comment: How did you derive $\{\pm \tan \frac {\pi}{5},\pm \tan \frac {2\pi}{5}\}$ from the quadratic?

Comment: I was taking your work above that $x=0$ when $x=\tan \theta$ and $\tan 5\theta = 0.$

Comment: Thank-you VERY much... a huge help.